# Flutter Get Data from Stepper TextFields

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get data from Stepper TextFields... always returns me null whatever field. In this case I am testing with Email. I follow this approach from Aseem Wangoo, which is seemed in this link: [here](https://github.com/AseemWangoo/flutter_programs/blob/master/StepperWithForm.dart). And used for my solution as follows:

```
List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKeys = [GlobalKey<FormState>(), GlobalKey<FormState>()];

class MyData {
  String _password;
  String _email;
  String _name;
  String _lastname;
}

class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey =  GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static var _focusNode =  FocusNode();
  static MyData data = new MyData();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  List<Step> steps = [
      Step(
        title: const Text('Crear cuenta'),
        isActive: true,
        state: StepState.indexed,
        content: Form(
          key: formKeys[0], 
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                autocorrect: false,
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._email = value;
                },
                maxLines: 1,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
                    return 'Please enter name';
                  }
                }, 
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Correo electrónico'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Ingrese su contraseña';
                      }
                      return null;
                },
                obscureText: true,
                autocorrect: false,
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._password = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Contraseña'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
      Step(
        isActive: true,
        state: StepState.indexed,
        title: const Text('Nombre y Apellido'),
        content: Form(
          key: formKeys[1],
          child:  Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._name = value;
                },
                autocorrect: false, 
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nombre'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._password = value;
                },
                autocorrect: false, 
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Apellido'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    ];

    int currentStep = 0;
    bool complete = false;

    next() {
      currentStep + 1 != steps.length
          ? goTo(currentStep + 1)
          : setState(() => complete = true);
    }

    cancel() {
      if (currentStep > 0) {
        goTo(currentStep - 1);
      }
    }

    goTo(int step) {
      setState(() => currentStep = step);
    }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  MustardColor,
                  FlanColor,
                  FlanLightColor
                ],
                stops: [0.1, 0.9, 1.5]
              )
            )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 180.0,
            width: 320.0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/crypto.png'),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 50.0),
          ),
          Center(child: 
            Container(
            height: 480.0,
            width: 320.0,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: FlanLightColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
            ),
          )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80.0,
            width: 200.0,
            child: Text('Regístrate',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              ),
            ),
            
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 120.0, right: 120.0, top: 180.0, bottom: 100.0),
          ),
          // STEPPER
    
          Center(
            child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            height: 380.0,
            width: 300.0,
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: 
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Stepper(
                          steps: steps,
                          currentStep: currentStep,
                          onStepContinue: next,
                          onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
                          onStepCancel: cancel,
                          controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                          {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                          return Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 80.0,
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                color: MustardColor,
                                onPressed: currentStep == 0 ? onStepContinue : () async {
                                  onStepContinue();
                                  // save the fields..
                                  final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
                                  if (!formState.validate()) {
                                    print('Please enter correct data');
                                  } else {
                                    formState.save();
                                      print("Email: ${data._email}"); // THIS RETURNS Email: Null
                                  }  
                                },
                                child: currentStep == 0 ? const Text('SIGUIENTE') : const Text('FINALIZAR'),
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                color: GoldColor,
                                onPressed: onStepCancel,
                                child: const Text('CANCELAR'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    ),
                  ])
            )
          ))
        ],)
        );
    }
}
```

Which is my error? Neither receive the value of a field nor is validating each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using TextEditingController

```
class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey =  GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static var _focusNode =  FocusNode();
  static MyData data = new MyData();

 static TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();
 static TextEditingController _passwordController  = new TextEditingController();
 static TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController();
 static TextEditingController _lastnameController = new TextEditingController();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  List<Step> steps = [
    Step(
        title: const Text('Crear cuenta'),
        isActive: true,
        state: StepState.indexed,
        content: Form(
          key: formKeys[0],
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                autocorrect: false,
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._email = value;
                },
                maxLines: 1,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
                    return 'Please enter name';
                  }
                },
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Correo electrónico'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Ingrese su contraseña';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                obscureText: true,
                autocorrect: false,
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._password = value;
                },
                controller: _passwordController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Contraseña'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    ),
    Step(
        isActive: true,
        state: StepState.indexed,
        title: const Text('Nombre y Apellido'),
        content: Form(
          key: formKeys[1],
          child:  Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._name = value;
                },
                autocorrect: false,
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nombre'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                onSaved: (String value) {
                  data._password = value;
                },
                controller: _passwordController,
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Apellido'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    ),
  ];

  int currentStep = 0;
  bool complete = false;

  next() {
    currentStep + 1 != steps.length
        ? goTo(currentStep + 1)
        : setState(() => complete = true);
  }

  cancel() {
    if (currentStep > 0) {
      goTo(currentStep - 1);
    }
  }

  goTo(int step) {
    setState(() => currentStep = step);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.blueAccent,
                        Colors.amber,
                        Colors.red
                      ],
                      stops: [0.1, 0.9, 1.5]
                  )
              )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 180.0,
            width: 320.0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/crypto.png'),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 50.0),
          ),
          Center(child:
          Container(
            height: 480.0,
            width: 320.0,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.cyan,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
            ),
          )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80.0,
            width: 200.0,
            child: Text('Regístrate',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              ),
            ),

            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 120.0, right: 120.0, top: 180.0, bottom: 100.0),
          ),
          // STEPPER

          Center(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                  height: 380.0,
                  width: 300.0,
                  child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child:
                      Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                                child: Stepper(
                                  steps: steps,
                                  currentStep: currentStep,
                                  onStepContinue: next,
                                  onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
                                  onStepCancel: cancel,
                                  controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                      {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                                    return Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 80.0,
                                        ),
                                        FlatButton(
                                          color: Colors.green,
                                          onPressed: currentStep == 0 ? onStepContinue : () async {
                                            onStepContinue();
                                            // save the fields..
                                            final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
                                            if (!formState.validate()) {
                                              print('Please enter correct data');
                                            } else {
                                              formState.save();
                                              print("Email: ${_emailController.value.text}"); // THIS RETURNS Email: Null
                                            }
                                          },
                                          child: currentStep == 0 ? const Text('SIGUIENTE') : const Text('FINALIZAR'),
                                        ),
                                        FlatButton(
                                          color: Colors.amber,
                                          onPressed: onStepCancel,
                                          child: const Text('CANCELAR'),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  },
                                )
                            ),
                          ])
                  )
              ))
        ],)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I prefer your answer as Correct Answer, because the solution by @chunhunghan doesn't save Name and Lastname

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: Move `steps` to `initState()`

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    ...
    steps = [
      Step(
```

Step 2: Modify `onStepContinue`

```
onStepContinue: () {
              setState(() {
                if (formKeys[currentStep].currentState.validate()) {
                  if (currentStep < steps.length - 1) {
                    currentStep = currentStep + 1;
                  } else {
                    currentStep = 0;
                  }
                }
              });
            },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppScreenMode();
  }
}

class MyData {
  String _password;
  String _email;
  String _name;
  String _lastname;
}

class MyAppScreenMode extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Steppers'),
          ),
          body: Signin(),
        ));
  }
}

class Signin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SigninState createState() => _SigninState();
}

class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {
  List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKeys = [
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>()
  ];
  static var _focusNode = FocusNode();
  static MyData data = new MyData();
  List<Step> steps;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print('Has focus: $_focusNode.hasFocus');
    });

    steps = [
      Step(
          title: const Text('Crear cuenta'),
          isActive: true,
          state: StepState.indexed,
          content: Form(
            key: formKeys[0],
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  focusNode: _focusNode,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  onSaved: (String value) {
                    data._email = value;
                  },
                  maxLines: 1,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
                      return 'Please enter name';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Correo electrónico'),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Ingrese su contraseña';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  obscureText: true,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  onSaved: (String value) {
                    data._password = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Contraseña'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
      Step(
          isActive: true,
          state: StepState.indexed,
          title: const Text('Nombre y Apellido'),
          content: Form(
            key: formKeys[1],
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  onSaved: (String value) {
                    data._name = value;
                    print("save $data._name");
                  },
                  autocorrect: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nombre'),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  onSaved: (String value) {
                    data._lastname = value;
                    print("save $data._lastname");
                  },
                  autocorrect: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Apellido'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  int currentStep = 0;
  bool complete = false;

  next() {

    currentStep + 1 != steps.length
        ? goTo(currentStep + 1)
        : setState(() => complete = true);
  }

  cancel() {
    if (currentStep > 0) {
      goTo(currentStep - 1);
    }
  }

  goTo(int step) {
    setState(() => currentStep = step);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white, Colors.white],
                        stops: [0.1, 0.9, 1.5]))),
            Container(
              height: 180.0,
              width: 320.0,
              child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 50.0, right: 50.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 50.0),
            ),
            Center(
                child: Container(
              height: 480.0,
              width: 320.0,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  //color: FlanLightColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
            )),
            Container(
              height: 80.0,
              width: 200.0,
              child: Text(
                'Regístrate',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 120.0, right: 120.0, top: 180.0, bottom: 100.0),
            ),
            // STEPPER

            Center(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                    height: 380.0,
                    width: 300.0,
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          child: Stepper(
                        steps: steps,
                        currentStep: currentStep,
                        onStepContinue: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (formKeys[currentStep].currentState.validate()) {
                              currentStep + 1 != steps.length
                                  ? goTo(currentStep + 1)
                                  : setState(() => complete = true);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
                        onStepCancel: cancel,
                        controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                            {VoidCallback onStepContinue,
                            VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                          return Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 80.0,
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                //color: MustardColor,
                                onPressed: currentStep == 0
                                    ? onStepContinue
                                    : () async {
                                        onStepContinue();
                                        print(currentStep);
                                        formKeys[currentStep]
                                            .currentState
                                            .save();
                                        print(
                                            "Email: ${data._email}");
                                        print(
                                            "name: ${data._name}");
                                        print(
                                            "lastname: ${data._lastname}");// THIS RETURNS Email: Null
                                      },
                                child: currentStep == 0
                                    ? const Text('SIGUIENTE')
                                    : const Text('FINALIZAR'),
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                //color: GoldColor,
                                onPressed: onStepCancel,
                                child: const Text('CANCELAR'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                    ])))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Works, but doesn't save Name and Lastname

Comment: full code updated and checked all work. you have two _password. also modified. please check again.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The final code, removing unnecessary things as Class MyData and save all, thanks to @junsu-cho

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../styles/colors.dart';
import '../../api/auth.dart';
import '../../views/calc/calc.dart';

class Signin extends StatefulWidget {
  Signin({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _SigninState createState() => _SigninState();
}

class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {

  static TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();
  static TextEditingController _passwordController  = new TextEditingController();
  static TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController();
  static TextEditingController _lastnameController = new TextEditingController();

  List<GlobalKey<FormState>> formKeys = [
    GlobalKey<FormState>(),
    GlobalKey<FormState>()
  ];

  List<Step> steps;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    steps = [
      Step(
          title: const Text('Crear cuenta'),
          isActive:  currentStep == 0 ? true : false,
          state: StepState.indexed,
          content: Form(
            key: formKeys[0],
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  controller: _emailController,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
                      return 'Ingrese su correo';
                    }
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Correo electrónico'),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Ingrese su contraseña';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  obscureText: true,
                  autocorrect: false,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Contraseña'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
      Step(
          isActive: currentStep == 1 ? true : false,
          state: StepState.indexed,
          title: const Text('Nombre y Apellido'),
          content: Form(
            key: formKeys[1],
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  controller: _nameController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Ingrese su nombre';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nombre'),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  controller: _lastnameController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Ingrese su apellido';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Apellido'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    ];
  }



  int currentStep = 0;
  bool complete = false;


  cancel() {
    if (currentStep > 0) {
      goTo(currentStep - 1);
    }
  }

  goTo(int step) {
    setState(() => currentStep = step);
  }

  _submitDetails() async {
    final FormState formState = formKeys[currentStep].currentState;
    if (formState.validate()) {
      formState.save();
      print('email');
      print(_emailController.value.text);
      print('nombre completo');
      print(_nameController.value.text + ' ' + _lastnameController.value.text);
      try {
        FirebaseUser result = await Provider.of<AuthService>(context).createUser(
          email: _emailController.value.text, 
          password: _passwordController.value.text, 
          firstName: _nameController.value.text, 
          lastName: _lastnameController.value.text
        );

        print('result:');
        print(result);

        if(result.email == _emailController.value.text){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Calc()),
          );
        } 


      } on AuthException catch (error) {
        return _buildErrorDialog(context, error.message);
      } on Exception catch (error) {
        return _buildErrorDialog(context, error.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  MustardColor,
                  FlanColor,
                  FlanLightColor
                ],
                stops: [0.1, 0.9, 1.5]
              )
            )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 180.0,
            width: 320.0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/crypto.png'),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 50.0),
          ),
          Center(child: 
            Container(
            height: 480.0,
            width: 320.0,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: FlanLightColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
            ),
          )
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80.0,
            width: 200.0,
            child: Text('Regístrate',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              ),
            ),
            
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 120.0, right: 120.0, top: 180.0, bottom: 100.0),
          ),
          // STEPPER
          Center(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                    height: 380.0,
                    width: 300.0,
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                          child: Stepper(
                        steps: steps,
                        currentStep: currentStep,
                        onStepContinue: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (formKeys[currentStep].currentState.validate()) {
                              print('steps lenght');
                              print(steps.length);
                              print('current step');
                              print(currentStep);
                              print('eval');
                              print(currentStep < steps.length - 1);

                              if (currentStep < steps.length - 1) {
                                currentStep = currentStep + 1;
                              } else {
                                setState(() => complete = true); 
                                _submitDetails(); 
                              }
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        onStepTapped: (step) => goTo(step),
                        onStepCancel: cancel,
                        controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                            {VoidCallback onStepContinue,
                            VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                          return Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 80.0,
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                color: MustardColor,
                                onPressed: onStepContinue,
                                child: complete ? const Text('REGISTRAR') : const Text('SIGUIENTE'),
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                color: GoldColor,
                                onPressed: onStepCancel,
                                child: const Text('CANCELAR'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                    ])))

        ],)
        );
    }
}

Future _buildErrorDialog(BuildContext context, _message) {
    return showDialog(
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error'),
          content: Text(_message),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
                child: Text('Cancelar'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                })
          ],
        );
      },
      context: context,
    );
}
```